# How to make the text decorationline line shorter in width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys I'm trying to figure out how to make the text-decoration-line shorter so it dosen't go all the way, i want it to look like this :

[image]

```css
#about h1 {
    font-weight: 600;
        font-size: 17px;
        color: #555;
     text-align: center;
        text-decoration-line: underline;
        text-decoration-style: wavy;
    }
```

```html
<div id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <h1> GET TO KNOW US </h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using bootstrap 3

Thanks

Comment: you want to keep the wavy one ? or you want this to work with any decoration ?

Comment: wavy one if thats possible @TemaniAfif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recreate it using gradient then put it inside a pseudo element then you can easily adjust size and position:

```css
h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

h1:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 12px;
  top: 100%;
  right:calc(50% - 40px);
  width:80px;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 100%, transparent 19%, gray 21%, gray 35%, transparent 35%, transparent), radial-gradient(circle at 50% 0%, transparent 19%, gray 21%, gray 34%, transparent 36%, transparent)-116px 0;
  background-size: 16px 16px;
  background-position: -9px 8px, 15px 3px;
}
```

```html
<h1> GET TO KNOW US </h1>
```

Comment: That's fantastic , the background will that work on ie iphone etc? or just google chrome

Comment: @RonTheOld yes, the radial-gradient is supported almost everywhere ;) but try and see maybe you will get some issue then we will try to fix them :)

Comment: Thats fantastic :)

Comment: If you're looking for something similar to the above image. consider using a repeated background image...

Comment: @JacobBelanger but it's not funny to use backgroud image ;) it's too easy and not good to handle changing color, shape ,etc

Answer (score 0):

Add a span and a pseudo class to it to get the red underline. You can change the width by adding more letters to the `content:...`

```css
#about h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #555;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  background-color:#fff;

}
.underline::before{
  content: " aasd";   
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration-line: underline;
  text-decoration-style: wavy;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: -29px;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <h1> GET TO KNOW US </h1><span class="underline"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pay attention that the underline is not controled by th width but by the amount of text inside the pseudo element